# Rudimentary bank program is going through the do loop infinately. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

Be gentle, this is my first time. :)

Here's the damage:  I'm in a non-major programming class that, so far, I've been doing well at.  But then there was this monster.  This project is just a simple bank program but I've had some issues with either it looping forever or char(s) not being known.

**Here is my code so far; if it looks odd or maybe done in a non-effecient way it is because that's where the class has taken me to.  FYI, next class is about arrays (no idea).**

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
* Bank program
* 
* @******** 
* @3
*/
public class Proj3also
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
System.out.println("Welcome to the banking program.");
System.out.println("");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter your starting balance: ");
double bal = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());
System.out.print("");
double deposit;
double withdraw;






do 
   {     System.out.print("Enter (d)eposit, (w)ithdraw, (b)alance check, or (q)uit: ");


   if (input == 'b' || input == 'B')
        {
            System.out.print("Your balance is: $");
            System.out.println(df.format(bal));
            System.out.println("");

        }


    else if (input == 'd' || input == 'D')
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the amount to deposit: ");
            deposit = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());
            bal = bal + deposit;
            System.out.println("");

        }
    else if (input == 'q' || input == 'Q')
        {
            System.out.print("");
            System.out.print("Exiting the banking program.  Goodbye!");


        }

    else if (input == 'w' || input == 'W')
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the amount to withdraw: ");
            withdraw = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());
            if (withdraw > bal)
            { 
                System.out.println("Transaction failed.  Withdraw amount cannot exceed balance.");
                System.out.println("");
            }
            else 
            {
                bal = bal - withdraw;

                System.out.println("");
            }  
    }
    } 
    while(input != 'q' || input != 'Q');  

}
```

}

This is what the instructor's program looks like:

http://i15.photobucket.com/albums/a376/decode_6/project3.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you actually read `input`? Something like `input = s.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is infinite, because its condition is always true:

```
    while(input != 'q' || input != 'Q');
```

If `input == 'q'`, then `input != 'Q'`, so the expression evaluates to true, and vice versa.
Your loop will never terminate. You need to change `||` to `&&` to make the condition logically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow my friend!

Have you tried changing the bottom while 'or' statement (||) to an 'and' (&&) -> while its not equal to 'q' AND not equal to 'Q', continue. Your current statement will always be true as it cannot be both.

i.e. change to -> while(input != 'q' && input != 'Q');

I cant find an online Java converter to test the theory, so let me know if this is wrong and i will delete the post.

Everyone gets caught out by Ifs and Ands at some point.